# How can i get the current schema name with Mybatis?

Tags: mysql, mybatis, spring-mybatis

Basically i need to know if there is any way to get the current schema name using Mybatis.
The DB engine I'm using is MySQL

Comment: What is the "current schema"?

Comment: The DB schema that Mybatis data source is referencing/using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most easy way, for which you don't even need to do anything MyBatis-specific, would simply be a query:

```
SELECT DATABASE();
```

This should, according to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_database), return the current database.

Alternatively, you should be able to get the `Configuration` from your `SqlSession` via `getConfiguration()` and get it from there somewhere, perhaps from the environment which allows you access to the DataSource, but you will probably need some database-specific code there.